# collection view is not showing the expected data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to display similar movie based on the movie ID is passed form table view didSelectRow function into collection view. Here is the URL which fetch the similar movie record. https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/129/similar?api_key=apikey. Here I am passing movie ID 129 and it fetch the similar movie. I can see in debug console I got the response correctly but it not showing the similar image into collection view. It little bit more code because I am following programmatic way to create the view .

Here is model code.. This is the generic struct Here I am passing Movie which decode the [Movie].

```
struct Page<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    
    let pageNumber: Int
    let totalResults: Int
    let totalPages: Int
    let results: [T]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pageNumber = "page"
        case totalResults = "total_results"
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
        case results
    }
    
}
```

Here is the URL network manager class ..

```
final class APIManager: APIManaging {
    
    static let shared = APIManager()
    
    let host = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3"
    let apiKey = "apikey"
    
    private let urlSession: URLSession
    
    init(urlSession: URLSession = .shared) {
        self.urlSession = urlSession
    }
    
    func execute<Value: Decodable>(_ request: Request<Value>, completion: @escaping (Result<Value, APIError>) -> Void) {
        urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest(for: request)) { responseData, response, error in
            if let data = responseData {
                let response: Value
                do {
                    response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.parsingError))
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                
                completion(.success(response))
            } else {
                completion(.failure(.networkError))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    private func urlRequest<Value>(for request: Request<Value>) -> URLRequest {
        let url = URL(host, apiKey, request)
        var result = URLRequest(url: url)
        result.httpMethod = request.method.rawValue
        result.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        return result
    }
    
}
```

Here is the function was called form view Model ..

```
static func similiar(for movieID: Int) -> Request<Page<Movie>> {
        return Request(method: .get, path: "movie/\(movieID)/similar")
    }
```

Here is the table view didSelect function . Here I am selecting the cell and navigate to details view ..

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movie = viewModel.state.movies[indexPath.row]
    let viewModel = MoviesDetailsViewModel(movie: movie, apiManager: APIManager())
    let viewController = CommonViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
    viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Here is the code for common view controller..

```
class CommonViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel
    private var viewController : UIViewController!
    
    init(viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         combineView()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.backButton(target: self, action: #selector(didTapBack(_:)))
    }
    
    private func combineView() {
        viewController = CommonViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        let dvc = MovieDetailsViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        let svc = SmiliarMovieViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        viewController.addChild(dvc)
        viewController.addChild(svc)
    }
    @objc private func didTapBack(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is the view model class ..

```
enum MoviesDetailsViewModelState {
    case loading(Movie)
    case loaded(MovieDetails)
    case pageLoaded(Page<Movie>)
    case error
    
    /// rest of the enum  here for movie and error..

    var page: Page<Movie>? {
        
        switch self {
        case .loading, .error, .loaded:
            return nil
        case .pageLoaded(let page):
          return page
        }
    }
}
final class MoviesDetailsViewModel {

    private let apiManager: APIManaging
    private let initialMovie: Movie
    var moviePage = [Movie]()

    init(movie: Movie, apiManager: APIManaging = APIManager()) {
        self.initialMovie = movie
        self.apiManager = apiManager
        self.state = .loading(movie)
    }

    var updatedState: (() -> Void)?

    var state: MoviesDetailsViewModelState {
        didSet {
            updatedState?()
        }
    }

    func fetchData() {
        apiManager.execute(MovieDetails.details(for: initialMovie)) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(let movieDetails):
                self.state = .loaded(movieDetails)
            case .failure:
                self.state = .error
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchSimilarMovie() {
        apiManager.execute(Movie.similiar(for: initialMovie.id)) { [weak self]  result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case.success(let page):
                self.state = .pageLoaded(page)
            self.moviePage = page.results
            case .failure(let error):
                self.state = .error
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my collection view code. Here I'm trying to display movie image for now.

```
import UIKit

class SmiliarMovieViewController: UIViewController {

    private let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel

    init(viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 80)

        let collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collection.dataSource = self
//        collection.delegate = self
        collection.register(SimilierMovieCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SimilierMovieCell.identifier)
        collection.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        return collection
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpUI()
    self.viewModel.updatedState = {[weak self] in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie()
}
    
    private func setUpUI() {
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width/2).isActive = true
}

extension SmiliarMovieViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let items = viewModel.moviePage.count
    return items
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SimilierMovieCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SimilierMovieCell
        
    let listMovie = viewModel.moviePage[indexPath.row]
    print(listMovie)
    cell?.configure(listMovie)
    return cell ?? SimilierMovieCell()
    }
}
```

Here is the cell code.

```
class SimilierMovieCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "CompanyCell"
    
    private lazy var companyImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()
    
    func configure(movieDetails: Movie) {
        contentView.addSubview(companyImageView)
        if let path = movieDetails.posterPath {
            companyImageView.dm_setImage(posterPath: path)
        } else {
            companyImageView.image = nil
        }
        let safeArea = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        companyImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor).isActive = true
        companyImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        companyImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        companyImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Here is the function to download the image..

```
func dm_setImage(posterPath: String) {
        let imageURL = URL(string: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/\(posterPath)")
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                self.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here is the screenshot of the result.  When I selected the tableview didselect and passing the movie ID form here I am expecting to show similar movies details at bottom of view now it empty.**
[image]

Comment: you don't see the similar movie result altogether simply because you are setting collection cell guy's top constraint incorrectly?

Comment: I don't think this is incorrect

Comment: In `SmiliarMovieViewController`, your `viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie()` is an asynchronous function.
It means that you have to **wait** until it is finished before you can use  `collectionView.reloadData()`.
So change `fetchSimilarMovie()` with a completion handler (look it up), and reload inside the handler.

Comment: I can do the fetch at didSelectRowAt at table view function as well where I can get the movie id for table view cell but it produce similar result.

Comment: let me update the  code

Comment: if you look at the code I will get the result which is an array and The Movie id get passed form didSelectRowAt and make API call get the similar movies and display into collection view but I do not know what is the reason it not working @workingdogsupportUkraine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchsimilarMovie()` inside `MoviesDetailsViewModel` calls an asynchronous method defined inside apiManager. Asynchronous execution does not block the codes and also does not guarantee the time when you get results. Therefore it is a must to add logic to update UI after you got the results back.

In your case, you wrote the code to change the state of `MoviesDetailsViewModel` after receiving the result from `apiManager.execute` function. But, you did not set what `updatedState` closure should do. Instead of just calling `collectionView.reloadData()` inside `viewDidLoad()` of `SmiliarMovieViewController`, you need to set it as what `updatedState` should do.

```
class SmiliarMovieViewController: UIViewController {

    private let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel

    init(viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
    //...
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpUI()
        
       // Set `updatedState`
        self.viewModel.updatedState = { [weak self] in
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        
        viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie()
        
    }
```

Hope this can achieve what you want to.

Comment: the result is same . Thanks

Comment: Is it because of `collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true`? CollectionView's top anchor is set to the view controller view's bottom anchor?

Comment: Yes I have change it to  collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true .. same result .

Comment: the CommonViewController is called from table view didselect . Inside the didselect have     viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie() function  to get the similar movie data based on the ID But the collection view is not able to catch it

Comment: The example picture you posted is `SmiliarMovieViewController`, no?

Comment: as you can see I am combining two view content into single view (CommonViewController) then calling it didSelectRowAt form MoviesViewController initial view. Then when I did select the table view cell I am expecting to show MovieDetailsViewController and SmiliarMovieViewController content . The image you see it  MovieDetailsViewController content but missing SmiliarMovieViewController content

Comment: no ... it not part of SmiliarMovieViewController

Comment: Okay. You can check if `SmiliarMovieViewController`'s viewDidLoad is called. Guess it is the problem with the view hierarchy..

Comment: here is the code override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpUI()
        self.viewModel.updatedState = {[weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie()
    }

Comment: I meant was that code actually fired?

Comment: I set up break point on viewDidLoad() on SmiliarMovieViewController's but never hitting there

Comment: So that view controller is not showing on the screen, that is why you don't see that collection view. I don't know about the design pattern of this project, if there is no particular reason for adding two different view controllers inside CommonViewController, I personally suggest you have only one view controller that contains every UIView element that you want to show (In this case might be UIImageView, UILabels, and UICollectionView in one UIViewController).