# UICollection view is not rendering properly

Tags: swift, uitableview, collections, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I am navigating to collection view when I select didSelectRowAt at table view. I am expecting to show collection view with configuration. But is not showing..

Here is the code for

```
    extension MoviesViewController {
    
            override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                let movie = viewModel.state.movies[indexPath.row]
                let viewModel = MoviesDetailsViewModel(movie: movie, apiManager: APIManager())
                let viewController = SmiliarViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
                viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie()
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Here is the view controller code for collection view..

```
import UIKit

class SmiliarViewController: UIViewController {

    private let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel

    init(viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    fileprivate let collectionView:UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.register(SimilierMovieCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CompanyCell")
        cv.backgroundColor = .brown
        return cv
    }()
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpUI()
        self.viewModel.updatedState = {[weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        viewModel.fetchSimilarMovie()
       
    }
    
    private func setUpUI() {
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        let safeArea = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        
    }
}

extension SmiliarViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let items = viewModel.moviePage.count
        return items
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SimilierMovieCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SimilierMovieCell
        
        let listMovie = viewModel.moviePage[indexPath.row]
        print(listMovie)
        cell?.configure(listMovie)
        return cell ?? SimilierMovieCell()
    }
}
```

When I clicked the table view cell and I am navigating to SmiliarViewController which got the collection view . but problem is not showing with layout.

Here is thee screenshot ..

[image]

Comment: `collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)`? So you are telling the top of the collection view to be at the bottom of `view`. Meaning: you are placing the collection view vertically below `view`, which is outside of the viewport. Replace `view.bottomAnchor` with `view.topAnchor`.

Comment: @JanMensch I already told him/her the same thing yesterday.  But he or she has dismissed it.

Comment: Please post the answer I will marked it as correct answer . Thanks

Comment: You already asked this question before 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78041995/collection-view-is-not-showing-the-expected-data and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032865/displaying-array-record-into-collection-view and
 then using some fake account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78028941/parsing-error-into-http-request-with-url-session
Asking the same question over and over is not well received in SO. When you do that you loose 
all the advice, trials, attempted answers and progress made in the other questions.

Comment: The aim of my last question was different to be more specific this one was for just for view property and it fixed now . But the last question was also included API response as well still same problem with suggestions form this questions. I am breaking down the problems small chunk and ask the question on small problem. It batter not to add all the error at the same question because it rise different issue as well .

Comment: The link you mentioned . As far I can see this is friend account. I also had discussions with her. I send her the same code . May be she is posted same question on same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [collection view is not showing the expected data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78041995/collection-view-is-not-showing-the-expected-data)

Comment: Not . I have refactor the code still same result .. @Skunka